# selenium cant intract with any element in this website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate building a database of photos of this website :
[mcmaster](https://www.mcmaster.com/)
it is using *ajax*.

but it's impossible to click on its first-page elements 
I have tried these codes :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("//span[@class='s7']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id("//a[span/@class='s7']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[5].click()
```

but it says *element not intractable*
and there is nothing else to locate the page elements with.

I just can't understand if a **a** tag is not clickable what is clickable?

Comment: Use .HP_1_1 > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) css selector instead.

Comment: what is the code ? I have not worked with that

Comment: Your first two lines are looking by ID but the locator you specified is an XPath. What links on the first page are you trying to click? There are 684 A tags on the first page alone.

Comment: I wanted to say that it doesn't work ... I know that there are 684 A tags there but I can't click on that

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.HP_1_1 > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **39** elements on the webpage https://www.mcmaster.com/screws which can be identified by using the *Locator Strategy*:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("//span[@class='s7']")
```

But all of those elements are not *visible* / *interactable*. So as an alternative to identify the elements within the **Fasteners** section as they appear within the webpage and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.mcmaster.com/')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[normalize-space()='Fasteners']//following::ul[1]//li/a")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Screws & Bolts', 'Threaded Rods & Studs', 'Eyebolts', 'U-Bolts', 'Nuts', 'Washers', 'Shims', 'Helical & Threaded Inserts', 'Spacers & Standoffs', 'Pins', 'Anchors', 'Nails', 'Nailers', 'Rivets', 'Rivet Tools', 'Staples', 'Staplers', 'Key Stock', 'Retaining Rings', 'Cable Ties', 'Lanyards', 'Magnets']
  ```

To click on the first element you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based *Locator Strategy*:

```
driver.get('https://www.mcmaster.com/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[normalize-space()='Fasteners']//following::ul[1]/li/a"))).click()
```

Comment: thank you it works but I have a new problem in this site , click on screws on the fist page . then you will have a page with a list . if I right click on each one and open it in a new page , there will be a A tag in the html of the page and in the new opened tab there will be a address in the address-bar like : https://www.mcmaster.com/screws/=ae03acbf4f3841a793074ddbe97b5552k7tf9wh3 . I'm trying to collect those addresses . please help me . A tags doesn't exist until I click on the items :(

Comment: please answer my question here

Comment: this one up here in comments